# Select application to open file

Tags: android, file, android-intent, mime-types

So I have a `ListView` of `PublicFile` Objects, which contains the `filecontent` (byte array) and the `filename` (string).
If I select a file from the list, I want to open it. In order to do that, I first save the file in a specific folder, and than I try to open it. The problem I am having is that no matter which file I select (txt, mp3, jpg, docx) it always opens the file with the android pdf reader. Logically I get an error that I can't open the file. I can only open pdf files.

```
publicDocs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        try{
            PublicFile selFile = (PublicFile) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myFolder");
            boolean success = true;
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                success = folder.mkdir();
            }
            if (success) {
                //safe file in order to open it later
                File file= new File(folder.getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ selFile.getFileName());

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
                fos.write(selFile.getFileContent());
                fos.close();

                //open file
                MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExt(file.getAbsolutePath()).substring(1));
                newIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file.getAbsoluteFile()),mimeType);
                newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(newIntent);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("could not open folder");
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Err:"+ex.getMessage());
        }

});


private String fileExt(String url) {
    if (url.indexOf("?") > -1) {
        url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
    }
    if (url.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) {
        return null;
    } else {
        String ext = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        if (ext.indexOf("%") > -1) {
            ext = ext.substring(0, ext.indexOf("%"));
        }
        if (ext.indexOf("/") > -1) {
            ext = ext.substring(0, ext.indexOf("/"));
        }
        return ext.toLowerCase();

    }
}
```

How can I solve the Problem? I also tried with adding the hardcoded mimetype but it still did not work.